# Not sure about violations of 3NF in the following relation

Tags: relational-database, 3nf

I have the following relation, but I am not sure about the violation of the 3NF:
`R={A,B,C,D,E,F,G}`
 FDs:
`{AF-->BCG, B-->DE, CG-->EF, E-->G}`

My keys are `{{A,F}},{{A,C,G}},{{A,C,E}},{{A,B,C}}`
With the following definition according to Wiki:

> X is a superkey, or
>   Every element of Y-X, the set difference between Y and X, is a prime attribute (i.e., each attribute in A-Y is contained in some candidate key)

Then the only violations would be `B-->DE` and `CG-->EF` because if X is not the superkey and therefore **every element** on the right side must be part a key? Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not sure about the second half of your question (from the Wiki definition downwards) but I see transitive dependencies and dependencies on part of a key, thus R is in 1NF only.

Comment: I was not just sure if every element on the RHS must be part of an key, and if so then if the two FDs above are the only ones who violate the 3NF.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Comment: Every element on the RHS doesn't need to be part of a key, but does need to depend on "the key, the whole key and nothing but the key" for 3NF.